# ReSwift - receive actions in the middle of animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation, redux

I'm trying to apply Redux in my iOS app with [ReSwift](https://github.com/ReSwift/ReSwift), but I still have some unanswered Redux questions.

1) How to handle receiving state updates in the middle of an animation?
Ex.: say some state change happened and triggered an animation, then I received another update (due to some data synchronization from the internet). How to handle that scenario? i.e., delaying that second update until the animation is finished.

2) Should I only send actions that change the state or is it ok to send actions just to trigger animation? Ex.: an action that would trigger some animation (say scrolling to some position in a `UIScrollView`) does not necessarily change any state (sure, I also have the state for the scroll position, but changing that state doesn't mean animating to the new scroll position, it could mean directly moving to it). I'm also triggering that animation conditionally in an action creator, after another action was dispatched and some other state was changed, so I can't just do that in the View component.

Answer (score 1):

The State and Action handling with ReSwift is surprisingly similar to Redux, but with strong typing.

There are two primary types of animations to deal with surrounding state. And summed up nicely by your two questions.

1. Animating **to** a state. State changes - as in your example - take a view from **any** valid state into the new state. If there are existing animations in progress, you can either cancel them (if possible with the animations you are doing), or queue the next animation.

   Most of the time, if the animations can be canceled, cancel them. If it's a list view, you don't have much choice. If you want to queue the animation, ignore any view changes while an animation is running and update a local copy of the latest state. Then make sure any animations trigger a completion block to compare the state, before and after the animation, and if the state is different, start another animation.
2. The second part sounds like you could treat them as triggered animations. Ie, login fails, the password field shakes for a second.

   Some of these can be handled by comparing the previous field value to the current, ie, `state.login_status` going from `.pending` to `.failed` would trigger the animation to start.

   You don't receive the raw Action stream though, just the `state`. Which is the same as Redux. I'd **encourage** using Actions even for events that may not effect the state. But the only way you see those actions is via middleware. Create a passive middleware object that filters the Action stream, and exposes them to a ViewModel or ViewController.

I know that does sound overly simplistic, but there is not too much to it. Just treat the Action stream as the single source of truth, the state as a projection of the stream, and the view as a projection of state. It feels limiting to start with, but makes it hard to go wrong.

Notes:

- At the moment it is implied that all Reducers will run on the main thread, but it is not enforced, and up to you to ensure the dispatching is done from the correct thread.

Comment: How do I queue the animations? Let's say I have 3 actions that change the same state `ActionA`, `ActionB`, `ActionC` (all causing animations), and `ActionB` and `ActionC` are sent in the middle of the animation from `ActionA`. I do not want to cancel any animation, nor do I want to go from the end of `animation A` to the beginning of `animation C`, I still want `animation B` to be triggered too. I can't just ignore the state changes while animating, or else `animation B` will not happen.

Comment: And when you say ignore any view changes, do you mean having a `ignoreUpdates: Bool` variable that would be checked in every `update` call and if it's `true`, I just `return`?

Comment: So my ViewController would have a sort of "reducer" to receive animation actions?